# Joomla! Custom Fields Making Website slow

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

Wokring on aplication that uses Joomla Custom Fields.
Joomla Site is extremely slow. When i first checked the MYSQL-Query log, it looks like that it is just doing a way to many queries.

Sql Log: https://pastebin.com/7YVH0ubJ

(This is the log of one page load. Really too many Queries.) We Have about 
200 Articles com_content that are loaded from DB. I dont know why there are so many queries. Im new to Joomla!

The problem is introduced by Joomla! Fields (See `josa9_fields_values` table). When Fields are disabled the site loads instantly.

Please someone has some hint for fields usage and optimization?

~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - don't use them :) If you want' to know more I touched this subject in my presentation about application performance optimization as JAB https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aas8oM7CLjk&feature=youtu.be